# Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port

Tags: c#, docker, google-cloud-platform

I have done everything precisely as I think I should. My application works if I run it on the cloud.
The commands I run:
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/**** 
gcloud run deploy *** --region us-central1 --platform managed --image gcr.io/t*** --allow-unauthenticated --port=26951

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.dll"]
```

Program:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static TcpListener tcpListener;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 26951);
   
            tcpListener.Start();
         
            tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(TCPConnectCallback, null);
           
        }
        private static void TCPConnectCallback(IAsyncResult _result)
        {
            TcpClient _client = tcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(_result);
        }
    }
}
```

CSProj:

```
<Project Sdk="***">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

All of which are in the same location

Comment: Why do you expect your code to work with Cloud Run? Cloud Run expects a response to an HTTP Request. Your code just closes the connection unless you are leaving out additional code.

Comment: @JohnHanley Oh wow thank you. So I guess my question then is where am I supposed to deploy this code then? Or is it that not possible on Google Cloud?

Comment: Edit your question with more details. Your code does not do anything other than listen, accept and close.

Comment: @JohnHanley I thought this was redundant. Here is all of my code: https://github.com/robin271/Server \ I still need to work on it on but the gist of this project is in my opinion conveyed; it is supposed to assign every incoming tcp connection to a individual server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to alter the dockerfile like so:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```